# Is there a standard way of discarding input in Rust?

Tags: io, rust, stdin

Reading input from `stdin` in Rust is pretty straightforward:

```
use std::io;

let mut some_string = String::new();
let _ = io::stdin().read_line(&mut some_string);
```

but sometimes you might want to just discard it without acknowledging it anywhere or procuring a buffer, like:

```
println!("Press Enter to close");
io::stdin().discard_input(); // discard_input() doesn't exist
```

It could read any number of characters until encountering `\n`, ignore it all and return nothing or `io::Result`. Is there a standard way of doing it or do I have to implement it myself? I traced the implementation of `read_line` to [`read_until`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/up/src/libstd/io/mod.rs.html#1119) implemented by `BufRead`, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to start from there.

Comment: You won't be able to get the "Press any key to continue" behavior with `stdin` alone. For example, when using a terminal you won't be able to read anything that the user typed before the user presses 'enter'.

Comment: The Enter limitation is fine for my needs. But out of curiosity, what else would be necessary to achieve that?

Comment: Reading from `stdin` in Rust also reads the `\n` character produced by pressing enter. So you can always read *something*. You should edit this into your question -- then someone can answer. About the question in the comment: platform specific features, basically.

Comment: What would be necessary is a proper keyboard API. Nothing in the standard library, but there are a various third party libraries. [glutin](https://crates.io/crates/glutin), for example. And of course, you can always go platform-specific, with things like the winapi crate, or whatever the equivalent is for your platform.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: e.g. calling `libc`'s `getchar()`, right? I'm after something simpler, though; I edited the question.

Comment: No, `getchar` also uses standard input.

Comment: This is much harder than I expected; I thought I was missing something silly.

Comment: I put in an impl since you said it was hard. Maybe you're referring to setting the terminal into unbuffered mode so that you can capture less than a line at a time. There's some crates for that.

Comment: Yes, I meant being able to just read 1 character (though it's nice that you provided an `impl` for the whole picture). I expect that there are crates for advanced stdin functionalities - I just hoped this could have been in an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `.discard_until_newline()` on stdin for example like this:

This should be a correct and efficient implementation (using a buffer to read, but not copying the read parts anywhere). It could be much simpler if you don't anticipate any long lines and just read a byte at a time, of course.

```
use std::io::Stdin;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

pub trait DiscardUntil {
    fn discard_until_newline(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error>;
}

impl DiscardUntil for Stdin {
    fn discard_until_newline(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let mut buffered = self.lock();
        loop {
            let (consume, done) = {
                let data = try!(buffered.fill_buf());
                if data.is_empty() {
                    (0, true)
                } else if let Some(newline_pos) = data.iter().position(|b| *b == b'\n') {
                    (newline_pos + 1, true)
                } else {
                    (data.len(), false)
                }
            };
            buffered.consume(consume);
            if done {
                break;
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("hi");
    io::stdin().discard_until_newline().unwrap();
    println!("again");
    io::stdin().discard_until_newline().unwrap();
    println!("goodbye");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with bluss's code and was able to come up with an implementation that has a little bit worse performance and is not well-suited to some corner cases (see comments below), but is simpler and shorter:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::{Stdin, BufRead};

pub trait DiscardUntil {
    fn discard_until_newline(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error>;
}

impl DiscardUntil for Stdin {
    fn discard_until_newline(&mut self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let mut buffered = self.lock();
        let amount = {
            let data = try!(buffered.fill_buf());
            data.len()
        };
        buffered.consume(amount);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

I welcome attempts to devise a simpler solution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Where do I risk it? And what could happen if I do?

Comment: When you consume all of the buffer, without checking if there is more than one line being read into it. Fill buf will attempt to fill the whole buffer (typically 8K). What happens if you do is that you are not true to the name of the method.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger it? I was unable to when I tested it.

Comment: Unable to trigger it does not mean that it does not exist. I prefer to write programs that are correct by construction, not "appear to be correct". Another case is when you consume *less than a line*. So one way would be to insert 8KB of data without a newline. To trigger the multiple lines case, I'd try for example pasting multiline text into the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I included this information in this answer.